# unable to start node project

Tags: node.js, npm

```
D:\freelancing\FlowerAppProject\WEBAPP_10_5>npm install
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.

> node@11.15.0 preinstall D:\freelancing\FlowerAppProject\WEBAPP_10_5\node_modules\node
> node installArchSpecificPackage

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.2 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @angular-material-extensions/password-strength@4.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/animations@^8.2.14 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular-material-extensions/password-strength@4.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/cdk@^8.2.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular-material-extensions/password-strength@4.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/common@^8.2.14 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular-material-extensions/password-strength@4.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@^8.2.14 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular-material-extensions/password-strength@4.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/forms@^8.2.14 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular-material-extensions/password-strength@4.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/material@^8.2.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@7.2.16 requires a peer of typescript@>=3.1.1 <3.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@7.3.10 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.4.0 < 3.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @pscoped/ngx-pub-sub@3.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^8.2.11 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @pscoped/ngx-pub-sub@3.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^8.2.11 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular-image-slider@0.0.9 requires a peer of @angular/animations@^8.2.13 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng-image-slider@2.5.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^8.2.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng-image-slider@2.5.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^8.2.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! file bash
npm ERR! path bash
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn bash
npm ERR! node@11.15.0 preinstall: `node installArchSpecificPackage`
npm ERR! spawn bash ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node@11.15.0 preinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hunter\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-15T13_23_06_391Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Please format this.

Comment: You need to delete package-lock.json

Comment: i did and also deleted node_modules folder but result is same

Comment: my node version is 11.0.0 and npm version is 6.4.1 does it have to do anything with this error??

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['npm run dev' command not working for windows with bash error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55496783/npm-run-dev-command-not-working-for-windows-with-bash-error) I think windows is the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - have you run `npm install -g angular` already?

If so -

Have you tried to manually install the missing dependencies?

```
npm WARN @angular-material-extensions/password-strength@4.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/animations@^8.2.14 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular-material-extensions/password-strength@4.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/cdk@^8.2.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular-material-extensions/password-strength@4.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/common@^8.2.14 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular-material-extensions/password-strength@4.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@^8.2.14 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular-material-extensions/password-strength@4.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/forms@^8.2.14 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular-material-extensions/password-strength@4.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/material@^8.2.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@7.2.16 requires a peer of typescript@>=3.1.1 <3.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@7.3.10 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.4.0 < 3.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @pscoped/ngx-pub-sub@3.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^8.2.11 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @pscoped/ngx-pub-sub@3.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^8.2.11 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular-image-slider@0.0.9 requires a peer of @angular/animations@^8.2.13 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng-image-slider@2.5.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^8.2.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng-image-slider@2.5.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^8.2.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

The package.json file should take care of this in theory, but obviously it is not.

You should go down the list and manually `npm install @angular/animations@^8.2.14` etc until all the entries are installed successfully and try again.

For some reason on your machine it's not automatically picking up the dependencies - I assume that you installed angular already or this whole project is coming from some tutorial you're following?

Answer (score 0):

These lines mean that it tries to run `bash` command but can not find it:

```
npm ERR! file bash
npm ERR! path bash
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn bash
npm ERR! node@11.15.0 preinstall: `node installArchSpecificPackage`
npm ERR! spawn bash ENOENT
```

I assume that you are running it under the Windows OS, where bash is absent (*if you are not running it under WSL e.g.*).